# How to architect/design a knowledge base to solve issues from its history analysis?

Tags: data-mining, data-warehouse, data-science, issue-tracking, knowledge-management

I have a ticketing system (lets say JIRA or similar) for my application to file an issue of my application. Now my requirement is to build a knowledge base in a way so that I can predict the solution of any similar issues in future by churning that knowledge base.

To explain further, the knowledge base would give me how many times this kind of issues have arisen in past and what have been the root cause of it in most of the time (lets say 80% time). This way the repository should have an analysis of each and every issue and its possible root cause plus many other relevant information about the issue.

Just to start off to build such a knowledge base, I need to know following things:

1. What is the most commonly used technology/mechanism available to achieve this ?
2. How do I need to architect/design a system to be able to serve this kind of requirement?
3. Does it require to learn any particular language/database ?

I request community experts to enlighten me with the required information and pointers to give me a starting point at least in this direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody please answer this question ?

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what you would like the knowledge base to be for? Do you want a knowledge base that just sits there with details on each issue? Isn't that actually the issue system itself? Or do you want there to be something that can provide predicted solutions whenever someone puts a new issue in? What does your ticket system provide in the way of recording root causes to help with guessing a possible root cause?

Comment: Your question is very broad, and architecture/design is a process that weighs up many options rather than someone being able to say to you, 'design it like this'.

Comment: @Rich I am looking out for something which would give predicted solution. Let's say I have maximum 250 tickets, based on which I want to carry out my analysis. I know that my question is very broad and giving impression that it lacks research effort. But trust me I have never got this kind of a problem ever before. I am not asking for a matured solution for this question which is kind of just an abstracted view. However, I am looking out for some baby steps to get started. I have some expertise on programming (Perl, Python) , database and queries (SQL, MySQL, Oracle, MongoDB etc). Thanks.

Comment: Worth revising your question to make it clear- as at present it reads that you would like a knowledge base, and you have specified that the knowledge base must have details and analysis of each issue. In fact you're interested in any way that technology could be used to help you highlight similar issues already raised, and from that to know probable solutions.

Comment: @Rich Because I thought to do a prediction it has to have some analysis in the background. That's why I am just asking an opinion or suggestion how can I start something which addresses similar problem. How it would do that may vary from person to person. Thanks

Comment: Yes it does, there will be some algorithm which might be simple, or it might be very data-sciency, but it doesn't necessarily need a completely separate knowledge base as the basis for its workings. But please note, stack overflow is not intended for questions like this which as you say are primarily opinion based or hints in a direction: it is for solutions to programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest against a ‘reinvent the wheel’ approach.
There are perfectly good tools out there that achieve your required use cases. Look at ServiceNow or Desk.com as CRM for tickets, or if you just want a Wiki that integrates with Jira, look at Atlassian’s wiki.
You can also generate reports from Jira itself, not sure why anyone would want to build his own when there are such great tools out there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will explore what you said. The continuous downvote suggests that my question has not been posted with proper explanation about what I want.  However your answer seems interesting and I will think something in that direction.